# LBA Harddisk Read using int 13h ah=42h in bootloader

Tags: assembly, bootloader, hard-drive, sector

I am trying to load Root directory of fat 16 partition using Int 13h Function ah = 42h! All parameters are correctly set to the best of my knowledge. Here is the code:`

```
    mov byte[DAP.sz],0x10
    mov byte[DAP.res],0
    mov cx,word[TotalRootDirSecs]
    mov word[DAP.count],cx
    mov word[DAP.offset],0x0500
    mov word[DAP.seg],0x0
    mov eax,dword[IstRootDirSec]
    add eax,dword[BPB_HiddSec]
    mov dword[DAP.baseLo],eax
    mov dword[DAP.baseHi],0x0
    mov di,5
    pusha
.loop:
    dec di
    cmp di,0
    jz .failed  
    mov si,0x0
    mov ds,si
    mov si,DAP
    mov dl,0x80
    mov ah,0x42
    int 0x13
    jc .loop
    popa
    mov si,RootLoaded
    call Print16
    cli
    hlt
.failed:
    mov al,ah
    add al,48
    mov ah,0eh
    int 0x10
    popa
    cli
    hlt`
```

Error code returned into ah is 1 that is Incorrect parameter( LBA out of range) but I dumped the registers and all values are correct.
Please anyone can tell where the mistake lies.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post `IstRootDirSec`, `BPB_HiddSec` and `DAP`.

Comment: I found the mistake. :) The mistake was I was using IstRootDirSec Variable as DWORD but it was a word and i have to convert it to DWORD.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was I was using IstRootDirSec Variable as DWORD but it was a word and i have to convert it to DWORD.

```
xor eax,eax
mov ax,word[IstRootDirSec]
add eax,dword[BPB_HiddSec]
```